# Xfbdev not found after including X (tinyx/kdrive) in Buildroot

Tags: x11, embedded, buildroot, framebuffer

I'm trying to add Xorg to an evaluation board for which I've already been provided with a working linux kernel. The evaluation board has an LCD display and I can confirm hardware & drivers are working by running a simple qt4 demo application.

To do so I have enabled the X11 option under "Graphical applications". These are the relevant configuration options:

```
BR2_PACKAGE_XORG7=y

#
# X11R7 Servers
#
BR2_PACKAGE_XSERVER_XORG_SERVER=y
BR2_PACKAGE_XSERVER_XORG_SERVER_VIDEODRV_ABI_24=y
BR2_PACKAGE_XSERVER_XORG_SERVER_VIDEODRV_ABI=24
BR2_PACKAGE_XSERVER_XORG_SERVER_V_1_20=y
# BR2_PACKAGE_XSERVER_XORG_SERVER_V_1_17 is not set
# BR2_PACKAGE_XSERVER_XORG_SERVER_V_1_14 is not set
BR2_PACKAGE_XSERVER_XORG_SERVER_VERSION="1.20.5"
# BR2_PACKAGE_XSERVER_XORG_SERVER_MODULAR is not set
BR2_PACKAGE_XSERVER_XORG_SERVER_KDRIVE=y
BR2_PACKAGE_XSERVER_XORG_SERVER_KDRIVE_EVDEV=y
BR2_PACKAGE_XSERVER_XORG_SERVER_KDRIVE_KBD=y
BR2_PACKAGE_XSERVER_XORG_SERVER_KDRIVE_MOUSE=y
```

The compilation concludes without issues. The board already contains uboot, linux kernel and a file system on flash; to test my modifications I update the linux kernel and then I chroot into the new file system created by buildroot after mounting it via nfs.

From there, I'd expect to run `xinit xterm` and see some output on the LCD. Unfortunately the server fails with the following error:

```
# xinit xterm

xinit: unable to run server "X": No such file or directory
Use the -- option, or make sure that /usr/bin is in your path and
that "X" is a program or a link to the right type of server
for your display.  Possible server names include:

    Xorg        Common X server for most displays
    Xvfb        Virtual frame buffer
    Xfake       kdrive-based virtual frame buffer
    Xnest       X server nested in a window on another X server
    Xephyr      kdrive-based nested X server
    Xvnc        X server accessed over VNC's RFB protocol
    Xdmx        Distributed Multi-head X server
```

Now, in the rootfs generated by buildroot there is `/usr/bin/X`, but it's just a link to `Xfbdev`:

```
$ ls usr/bin/X -l
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 6 Oct  1 14:44 usr/bin/X -> Xfbdev
```

Unfortunately there is no such thing as `Xfbdev` in the same folder; when mounting the file system via nfs the `X` link simply disappears because its destination is not found.

I realize I'm skipping a lot of steps here (assuming the framebuffer driver works because I can see an qt4 standalone application), but I can't wrap my head around the fact that `Xfbdev` is not present in the `rootfs`.

If I understand correctly `Xfbdev` would be a tiny version of `X11`, enabled by buildroot when selecting tinyX/kdrive as Xorg server. So why is there no executable in `/usr/bin`, but just the symbolic link to it?

Comment: Your qt application was running directly on the framebuffer, like `/dev/fb0` and this still works with the modified system?

Comment: I can confirm it works with the new kernel, but I haven't tried it in the chrooted file system

Comment: Update - I have tried to use a direct framebuffer application and it works in the chrooted system as well.